# XmlDocument.Save unhandled exception thrown from GC thread

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I develop a simple app, when i try to save an XMLDocument to a thumb drive which doesn't have enough free space, weird thing happens. Though i already added "try catch" clause for XMLDocument.Save(filePath), i still get an unhandled exception, and the exception seems to be thrown from GC finalization thread (seems GC tries to flush another 4096 bytes which the disk does not have). I think it is a common scenario to use XMLDocument object , i wonder what is wrong?

code snippet:

```
XmlDocument query = new XmlDocument();
query.Load("g:\\test.xml");
... //modify the content of query to make it bigger
try
{
  query.Save("g:\\test.xml");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
```

Exception stacktrace as below:

> mscorlib.dll!System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int errorCode = 112, string maybeFullPath = "") + 0x498 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) + 0x119 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(bool calledFromFinalizer) + 0x22 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(bool disposing = false) + 0x57 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.Finalize() + 0x1b bytes

Comment: What is the error Message with exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory exception while XDocument.Save()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059966/memory-exception-while-xdocument-save)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem is that some code *somewhere* isn't disposing of the `FileStream` when it's done with it. When the `FileStream` is finalized, it's trying to flush the data - at which point the exception is being thrown.

If that really is all of your code, it *sounds* like it's a bug in `XmlDocument.Save()`, which should definitely close all its streams before returning. You could work around this by opening the `FileStream` yourself (with a `using` statement) and passing the stream to `XmlDocument.Save` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply! It works! but does this mean XMLDocument class do have a bug? because i think just fowllow a common scenario to use it.

Comment: @user1077127: It sounds like it does, yes. I can't say for sure, but it seems odd to me that it doesn't close the stream explicitly. You may want to file a bug on Connect.