# C#.Net: XML Document.Save throws a IOException

Tags: c#, xml

Intermittently, I see an IO exception at XMLDocument.Save(). Initially, I thought it's the same as question in the following links:
1. [XmlDocument.Save unhandled exception thrown from GC thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354668/xmldocument-save-unhandled-exception-thrown-from-gc-thread)
2. [Memory exception while XDocument.Save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059966/memory-exception-while-xdocument-save)

But, My call stack is different from the ones discussed in above threads. Here is my call stack:
------- Base Exception (start here) ---------
Root cause may be due to this exception: 'System.IO.IOException' 
Message=IOException,

```
StackTrace=   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Indent(Boolean beforeEndElement)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.AutoComplete(Token token)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlDOMTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter xw)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
```

Problem is my IOException doesn't quote any reason. 
Following is the code:

```
XmlDocument traceXml = new XmlDocument();
traceXml.Load(traceFilename);
XmlElement root = t30Trace.DocumentElement;
XmlAttribute jobId = t30Trace.CreateAttribute("JobId");

jobId.Value = "45";
root.Attributes.Append(jobId);

traceXml.Save(traceFilename);
```

Wanted to understand more on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error (not call stack)? It might be a permission issue or simultaneous access issue. Can you check if you can open the file? Verify that nothing else is accessing the file when you're running your code too

Comment: Thanks Tyress. We couldn't check this for the reason that this test was run in a VM and has already got shut down when we started the triage. I've checked at other IOexceptions, they usually give a clear message indicating what caused the exception i.e,Diskfull, Illegal access, etc.,

Comment: Is more than one user writing to file or your application writing the same file more than once?  This looks like a window exception that the user can't write file because it was already opened.  Make sure you dispose the Filestream before opening the file a 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in an answer to similar question(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354736/4151626), states that there is probably a bug in `XmlDocument.Save()` that incorrectly pins the stream.  By taking direct control of the creation and disposition of the stream outside of the `XmlDocument.Save()` method I was able to get around this halting error.

```
//e.g.
XmlWriter xw = new XmlWriter.Create(traceFilename);
traceXml.Save(xw);
xw.Close();
xw.Dispose();
```